# Entity Framework throwing exception with Extension Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code in my Controller:

```
public List<DockDoorViewModel> GetDoorViewModel()
{
    List<DockDoorViewModel> doors = new List<DockDoorViewModel>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        // This is where the Stack Trace is pointing to.
        DockDoorViewModel door = db.vwDockDoorDatas
                                   .Where(x => x.DockNo == i)
                                   .Select(x => x.ToDockDoorViewModel())
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

        if (door == null)
        {
            door = new DockDoorViewModel(i);
        }
        else
        {
            door.Items = db.vwDockDoorDatas
                           .Where(x => x.DockNo == i)
                           .Select(x => x.ToDockDoorItem())
                           .ToList();
        }

        doors.Add(door);
    }

    return doors;
}
```

I am getting this exception when I try and Run the Web App:

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DockDoorMonitor.Models.DockDoorViewModel ToDockDoorViewModel(DockDoorMonitor.Models.vwDockDoorData)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is the extension method:

```
public static class vwDockDoorDataExtensions
{
    public static DockDoorViewModel ToDockDoorViewModel(this vwDockDoorData x)
    {
        DockDoorViewModel vm = null;

        if (x != null)
        {
            vm = new DockDoorViewModel()
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                DockNo = x.DockNo,
                loadType = x.loadType,
                LoadDescription = x.LoadDescription,
                Name = x.Name,
                LocationCode = x.LocationCode,
                SACode = x.SACode
            };
        }

        return vm;
    }

    public static DockDoorItem ToDockDoorItem(this vwDockDoorData x)
    {
        DockDoorItem vm = null;

        if (x != null)
        {
            vm = new DockDoorItem()
            {
                ID = x.ItemNo,
                Description = x.Description,
                Quantity = x.Quantity,
                UnitOfMeasure = x.UnitOfMeasure
            };
        }
        return vm;
    }
}
```

I've done this kind of thing before so I'm not seeing what I am doing wrong?  This is my first time with a MVC5 and EF6 application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know really - EF can't translate your extension methods to SQL therefore throws an exception. You need to convert your query from LINQ to Entities to LINQ to Objects, this can be done with a simple call to `AsEnumerable()` e.g.

```
DockDoorViewModel door = db.vwDockDoorDatas.Where(x => x.DockNo == i)
                                           .AsEnumerable()
                                           .Select(x => x.ToDockDoorViewModel())
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Effectively, what this does is create a hybrid query where everything before the `AsEnumerable` is translated and executed as SQL and the remainder being executed client-side and in memory.

---

As per your performance issues, looking at your query again you are unnecessarily pulling across a lot of records, you are only after the first one so why not just pull that one over i.e.

```
vwDockDoorData entity = db.vwDockDoorDatas.Where(x => x.DockNo == i)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();
DockDoorViewModel door = entity != null ? entity.ToDockDoorViewModel() : null;
```

A further improvement on that would be to simply filter the records *before* you iterate them (give you have a start/end range) e.g.

```
var doorDatas = db.vwDockDoorDatas.Where(x => x.DockNo >= 1 && x.DockNo <= 11)
                                  .ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < doorDatas.Count; i++)
{
    // This is where the Stack Trace is pointing to.
    DockDoorViewModel door = data.ToDockDoorViewModel();
    if (door == null)
    {
        door = new DockDoorViewModel(i+1);
    }
    else
    {
        door.Items = data.ToDockDoorItem();
    }
    doors.Add(door);
}
```

The above would only require a single trip to the DB.

Comment: This works, thanks.  Now I just need to figure out why it's so RIDICULOUSLY slow.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin well remember the majority of your query is now running in memory now so depending on the result set the results could be pretty slow. How many results are you pulling?

Comment: 130 from a SQL View.  About 15 columns.  Non "wide" though the View itself does take 4 sec's to run in Management Studio.  A question, does the view have to "re-run" everytime I am looping over it?

Comment: So I added this: `var data = db.vwDockDoorDatas.ToList();
`  right before my `for` loop and performance skyrocketed.  I saw your note about `Enumerable` but that didn't change anything.  Perhaps I shouldn't be using a SQL View for this.  Sproc maybe...

Comment: @RefractedPaladin "*does the view have to "re-run" everytime I am looping over it*?" - that purely depends on the nature of your loop, could you post an example? Calling `ToList` will return your *entire* resultset so I am not surprised...

Comment: I mean the `for` loop already posted.  That `db.vwDockDoorDatas` is a SQL View.  I mean it's obviously in EF but behind it is a SQL View.  I am GUESSING that it was regenerating that view everytime I was calling it, in both spots, and each iteration of the Loop.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin ah sorry skimmed over that. Yeah the code you have at the moment is going to query the DB on *every* iteration (twice if you need to get the Items as well). Given you have a start range and an end range, it makes better sense to pre-optimize the query before you execute it i.e. before your loop do `var doors = db.vwDockDoorDatas.Where(x => x.DockNo >= 1 && x.DockNo <= 11).ToList();`. Then you iterate over `doors` which means a single trip to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to load the data from the SQL Server before using your to method. You can do this (for example) with the following command:

```
door.Items = db.vwDockDoorDatas
                           .Where(x => x.DockNo == i)
                           .ToList() //Possibly use AsEnumerable() here instead as James says
                           .Select(x => x.ToDockDoorItem())
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: It's generally better to opt for `AsEnumerable` in these sort of circumstances because you still retain the delayed execution.